# How to add a index by set of data when using rbindlist?

Tags: r, csv, data.table

I have several different csv files with the same structure. I read them into R using fread, and then union them into a bigger dataset using `rbindlist()`.

```
files <- list.files( pattern = "*.csv" );
x2csv <- rbindlist( lapply(files, fread, stringsAsFactors=FALSE), fill = TRUE )
```

The code works weel. However, I would like to add a column filled with numbers to indicate from which csv file that observation came from. For exemple, the output should be:

```
       V1        V2         V3  C1
   1:   0 0.2859163 0.55848521   1
   2:   1 1.1616298 0.87571349   1 
   3:   2 2.1122510 0.95062116   2 
   4:   3 2.6832013 0.57095035   2
   5:   4 2.9117493 0.22854804   2 
   6:   5 2.9886040 0.07685464   3
```

where C1 is the new index column telling that: the first and second observations come from files[1] (the first .csv file); the third and fourth observation come from files[1] (the first .csv file); and so on.

Comment: There is an argument for this in `?rbindlist`, `idcol=` I think.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an enhanced version of [Nicolás' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45515611/3817004) which adds the file names instead of numbers:

```
x2csv <- rbindlist(lapply(files, fread), idcol = "origin")
x2csv[, origin := factor(origin, labels = basename(files))]
```

- `fread()` uses `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` by default so we can save some keystrokes
- Also `fill = TRUE` is only required if we want to read files with differing structure, e.g., differing position, name, or number of columns
- The id col can be named (the default is `.id`) and is populated with the sequence number of the list element.
- Then, this number is converted into a factor whose levels are labeled with the file names. A file name might be easier to remember than just a mere number. `basename()` strips the path off the file name.

Answer (score 2):

You are only missing the `idcol` argument from `rbindlist()`. Run:

```
x2csv <- rbindlist(lapply(files, fread, stringsAsFactors = FALSE), fill = TRUE, idcol = TRUE )
```